# Hypothesis testing for similarity of data-driven "curves"

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I wonder how to carry out statistical hypothesis testing (my field loves that :/) on data of this sort:
[image: data example]

I.e. we have 2 groups, 4 samples in each (unpaired). Each sample is recorded in 4 conditions, where these have a natural ordering (i.e., the value on the x-axis matters - this could be taking measurements of the sample over time, or in increasing concentration of something, etc. (but it's not actually concentration, so I cannot use the EC50-shift approach)). The curves are generally expected to be of the form that they are constant for some time and then they increase.

Using multiple t-tests (normality is generally ok) is not ideal (although I'd think that for low number of x-axis values and the reader interpreting the p-values together with actual data, it might not be such a drastic problem). ANOVA is sometimes used to do this (independent variables corresponding to different x-axis values, dependent being y-axis), but it seems rather inappropriate to me too. As far as I know, ANOVA was designed for case where the independent variables are indeed reasonably independent - but here they are clearly not, as they are sequentially ordered. As a consequence, if we alter the order of the x-axis (e.g. swapping contents of x=4 with x=1), we would have a very different interpretation of such data, while the p-value from ANOVA is the same - it just does not care. Another feature I dislike is that if we took the plot above, we could very easily tweak the ANOVA p-value by carrying out experiments in the region between 1 and 2 (making it nonsignificant, assuming it behaves as if we linearly interpolated), or between 3 and 4 (making it significant, with the assumption it behaves as if it was interpolated between behaviour at 3 and 4).

For the same reasons, doing a straightforward multiple hypothesis testing correction on multiple tests also does not consider the information on the ordered x axis (which is a problem for us, given limited statistical power).

How could one approach this? As mentioned above, we can probably make the assumption that the curves are first flat for a while (possibly with distinct offset - which would be a meaningful difference too), and then increase.

Comment: Do you have the individual id's (1,2,3,4) for the group members? Can you clarify what is the null hypothesis? Maybe a repeated measures analysis, or a permutation test?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes, we do have a mapping from each point to both x and y axis.

Null hypothesis is a good question, and its vagueness might be a part of the problem - in general, it's something along the lines of "the offset and temporal trend do not differ between groups". So one might also try to fit a polynomial model and then work on the coefficients?